# portfolio rebalancing each period to get back initial weights

Tags: python, pandas, finance

So I have 4 stocks and I would like to understand how to rebalance a portfolio. Let say each stock should keep a weight of 0.25 (1/4) and I only invest 1 dollar in total

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

stocks = pd.DataFrame([[52.38, 45.22, 12.01, 120.94],
                      [51.25, 42.35, 13.32, 123.90],
                      [53.40, 44.18, 15.11, 120.54],
                      [56.98, 47.89, 14.65, 118.98]], columns = ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'])

target_weights = {'w':0.25, 'x':0.25, 'y':0.25, 'z':0.25}
```

So I first need to compute the returns of each stock:

```
returns = stocks.pct_change()
```

and so the difference from the target weight and its return gives me the new allocation right since I invest only 1 dollar? But now, how do I rebalance the weights to get the target weights back and still have a total allocation of 1, and this for each period. I think the computations should  be done in a for loop and at each iteration it starts back with the target weights but I don't know how I should handle that.

Comment: `shares = target_weights / stocks` would create a dataframe with the number of shares for each stock over time required to keep the weighting constant over time.  You could then calculate the difference between rows to see how many shares need to be bought/sold each time (for $1, and I have assumed the stock prices above are also in USD$, these will all be small fractions of shares bought, sold and held over time).

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to do this in numpy than in pandas:

```py
# Price of w, x, y, z at the beginning of each period
price = np.array(
    [
        [52.38, 45.22, 12.01, 120.94],
        [51.25, 42.35, 13.32, 123.90],
        [53.40, 44.18, 15.11, 120.54],
        [56.98, 47.89, 14.65, 118.98],
    ]
)
# The number of shares for each security in the portfolio
# at the beginning of each period
quantity = np.zeros_like(price)

initial_investment = 1
target_weight = np.array([0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25])

for i in range(price.shape[0]):
    if i == 0:
        quantity[i] = initial_investment * target_weight / price[i]
    else:
        portfolio_value = (quantity[i-1] * price[i]).sum()
        quantity[i] = portfolio_value * target_weight / price[i]

# Final assembly
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["price", "quantity"], list("wxyz")])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([price, quantity]), columns=columns)
df["portfolio_value"] = (df["price"] * df["quantity"]).sum(axis=1)
```

Result:

```
   price                        quantity                               portfolio_value
       w      x      y       z         w         x         y         z                
0  52.38  45.22  12.01  120.94  0.004773  0.005529  0.020816  0.002067        1.000000
1  51.25  42.35  13.32  123.90  0.004937  0.005975  0.018996  0.002042        1.012128
2  53.40  44.18  15.11  120.54  0.004966  0.006003  0.017552  0.002200        1.060818
3  56.98  47.89  14.65  118.98  0.004780  0.005687  0.018590  0.002289        1.089362
```

Comment: thank you! I think I understand the logic